# C# Regex to split using space but exclude text between [: and :] special characters

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, split, special-characters

I need two C# Regular expressions to split using space but exclude text between **[:** and **:]** special characters.

1. Need regex to split text but exclude text between **[:** and **:]** special characters.
2. Need regex to split text but exclude text between **[:** and **:]** and also the text between **[** and **]** special characters.

**Example: 1st Case:**

```
string input1 = "one [two two] three [:four four:] five six [seven seven:] [:eight eight]";
```

**output:**

```
one
[two
two]
three
[:four four:]
five
six
[seven
seven:]
[:eight
eight]
```

**Example: 2nd Case:**

**output:**

```
one
[two two]
three
[:four four:]
five
six
[seven
seven:]
[:eight
eight]
```

I tried this but not working, producing below output

```
string input1 = "one [two two] three [:four four:] five six [seven seven:] [:eight eight]";
var parts1 = Regex.Matches(input1,  @"[[::]].+?[\[::]]|[^ ]+").Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => m.Value)
                        .ToArray();
```

```
one
[two two] three [:four four:]
five
six
[seven seven:]
[:eight
eight]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var pattern = @"\[:[^][]*:]|\[(?!:)[^][]*(?<!:)]|\S+";
var results = Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/84Temj/1).

*Details*:

- `\[:` - `[:` string
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `:]`
- `|` - or
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?!:)` - immediately on the right, there should be no `:`
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `(?<!:)]` - a `]` char that has no `:` right before it
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

Comment: met my requirement, Thanks @Wiktor

Answer (score 0):

I think your input case might be wrong, it should be `string input1 = "one [two two] three [:four four:] five six [:seven seven:] [:eight eight:]";`

And you can use this regex to have the desired array:

`var parts1 = Regex.Replace(input1, @"\[\:[a-z ]+\:\] *|\[[a-z ]+\] *", "").Trim().Split(' ');`